# c# Winform Controls with VSTO addin keep Excel responsive

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, vsto, excel-addins

I am new to VSTO Excel Addin and Winforms. I have created an addin, which launches a winform page with few check boxs, a button and one label to tract status.

[image]

As soon as the winform launches, my excel is not responsive. I would like to make excel responsive even with winform open (and with button "Done" click). Button will run a long running process. How can I achieve that? Any pointers?

This is what I have 
Ribbon Class:

```
public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 fs = new Form1();
            fs.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
```

Form Class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Processing please wait";
            await Task.Run(() => { longRunningProcess(); });
            label1.Text = "File 1 Processed";
        }
         public void longRunningProcess()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

Update:
Using .show works but I am unable to access label1.Text and get error as :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'
```

[image]

Comment: Try open your form with: ‘Show’

Comment: Beware: if you need to make changes to the Excel object model after this window closes, you should keep it modal or move it into an action/task pane.

Comment: @Sievajet 'Show' works but line label1.Text = "File 1 Processed"; fails with error. 

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Use ‘Invoke’ to marshal to the UI thread

Comment: @Sievajet thanks for the pointer. with this line it works :

label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                label1.Text = "Test";
            });

Comment: @Sievajet Could add your answer ? so that, I can mark as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your form with `Show` and use`Invoke` to marshal back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

@Sievajet helped solve this.  Posting code, in case someone needs it.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Processing please wait";
            await Task.Run(() => { longRunningProcess(); });
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                label1.Text = "File 1 Processed";
            });
        }
```

Comment: Actually you don’t need the Invoke because the continuation after the Await will be posted on the UI thread

Comment: And if it still throws the UI exception. You’ve probably initiated the update or await on a worker thread. The await needs to be called on the UI thread in order to continue on that thread

Comment: Thanks. I will research into this more.